# Make full bounding area of SVG shape clickable

Tags: svg

I have an SVG map with some pins on it that need to be clickable. Furthermore, a small animation is activated whenever the user hovers over one of the pins on desktop. My issue is that it is only the actual shape that receives the event, which is problematic, as the pins have a little "hole" in its center, so if the user hovers or clicks in the center of the pin nothing happens. Is there a way to make the event trigger whenever the user clicks or hovers over the bounding box of the shape, ie. the area is outlined when the element is viewed in the inspector, or would I have to extend the actual SVG with an invisible box or some other "hacky" solution"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you'll need to add an invisible rectangle on top. You'll want to set that rectangle to `pointer-events: fill`, so it gets click events even though it is invisible.